# Google play payment pop-up comes up completely blank and white

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am trying to get inApp billing testing in android. for this I
a-included a ready made library,
b- paid and become a member of Google play
c- uploaded my test app with the right app license_Key from google play
d- added the right line in the manifest
e- added android.test.purchased and android.test.cancelled as the SKU
f- run the billing libraries.  They all could connect, receive  these two skus
but when I try to purchase either of these SKUs google play payment pops up with a white and blank screen.  When I swipe it I receive user cancelled error.

Why I cannot see populated google play payment screen, I am puzzled.  I cannot test if all needed inApp purchase functionalities are working.  Please direct me!!

I tried running trivialdrive from playstore, I get proper playstore purchase screen.  So there is nothing wrong with my phone settings.

I expected a populated purchase screen from Google but now receiving nothing

Comment: did your issue solved? I'm having the same problem and raised the issue here https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/63